# Angular 4 project deployed on Tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm building Angular 4 project project with the below command

```
 ng build --target=production --base-href /project1
```

When I deploy the project to tomact 8 the app works when i place the index file on

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.44_2\webapps\project1
```

and the app assets and other files on the root folder.

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.44_2\webapps\ROOT
```

How can i place all the apps resources on the project folder.

Thanks

after project build my index.html looks like this.

```
 <base href="/project1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

 <link href="styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.463ebb8a59179d418824.bundle.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.d90888e283bda7f009a0.bundle.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.8715d5c83a3b32855527.bundle.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.b467d247e3cfe82bdeeb.bundle.js"></script>
```

if I append /project1 on each source link the app is launching from the project1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

can you try base-href="./" like 
ng build --target=production --base-href ./

Answer (score 0):

If your are using angular-cli command to create  angular 2 project.Then cli has given some commands to deploy your application into production. Use command like **ng build --prod** on your project directory and it will generate **dist** folder in your directory.[image]

Go to inside dist folder and change the base href like **href="."** in index.html. After that copy dist folder in your tomcat root directory and run the server.[image]. you can see below screen shot our application running on tomcat server.
[image]